# iPhone: Sequencing issue with creating file with "do not back-up" flag in Documents folder?

Tags: iphone, backup, icloud

Our applications set the "do not back-up" flag as per Apple's requirements. Or at least we thought so. A recent submission has been rejected because the reviewer found a file without the flag set. We tested, re-tested and tested again and see that all of our files are created with the "do not back-up" flag. Hmmm!

This is not our first application using the same code base. We've had many others pass through with no issues even some quite recently.

So could it be a sequencing problem? We are copying a database file out of the download bundle that is used as the application's starting content; this content is then updated as the user gets more data. The initial database file can be large - as big as 2MB - depending on the application. We open a new file in the Documents folder, copy the database contents to the new file, close it, and then set the "do not back-up" flag.

Instead should we create an empty file and then immediately set the "do not back-up" flag, prior to opening it to overwrite the empty file with the database contents from the bundle?

I've asked the Apple reviewers this question but have not received an answer yet. I could simply try the different sequence and see what happens in the re-review, but I'd prefer to know what I should be doing and do it, rather than guess what the problem is and shoot in the dark.

So does anyone know of a sure-fire "Apple approved" way to copy out a (database) file from the bundle into the Documents directory and set the "do not back-up" flag? Can anyone shed light on any similar rejections and what they did to please the reviewers?

Answer (score 0):

Having earned the Tumbleweed badge (= its a boring question) here is some information to answer it....

The way to set the "do not back-up" flag has changed between 5.0.1 and 5.1. The [release notes for iOS 5.1 SDK](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/General/RN-iOSSDK-5_1/_index.html) has the following entry under "Backup"

> iOS 5.1 introduces a new API to mark files or directories that should not be backed up. For NSURL objects, add the NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey attribute to prevent the corresponding file from being backed up. For CFURLRef objects, use the corresponding kCFURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey attribute.
>   Apps running on iOS 5.1 and later must use the newer attributes and not add the com.apple.MobileBackup extended attribute directly, as previously documented. The com.apple.MobileBackup extended attribute is deprecated and support for it may be removed in a future release.

Note that iCloud was introduced in iOS 5.01, and this change was introduced in 5.1, which means that the app must adapt to the iOS specific version running on the device. One of our developers found the following [Gist for code that handles pre- and post- iOS 5.1](https://gist.github.com/1999985)  devices.